# Reading an audio file through Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I want to make a GUI in matlab that has 2 buttons. 1 Button (pushbutton1) loads the selected file and the second button (pushbutton2) executes a code.
This is what i have so far

```
    % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1. function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, ventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    [filename pathname] = uigetfile({'*.wav'}, 'Select File');
    fullpathname = strcat (pathname, filename);
    audio = wavread(fullpathname);


    % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    % get a section of vowel
    [x,fs]=wavread('audio',[24120 25930]);    
    ms20=fs/50; % minimum speech Fx at 50Hz

    % plot waveform
    t=(0:length(x)-1)/fs; % times of sampling instants
    subplot(2,1,1);
    plot(t,x);
    legend('Waveform');
    xlabel('Time (s)');
    ylabel('Amplitude');
```

The mistake is in the following line

```
    [x,fs]=wavread('audio',[24120 25930]);
```

How should I write it?

Also when plotting how do I make the plot appear on the GUI ?

Comment: I think you might need to include the `.wav` extension to the filename. Also, when you create the GUI you will create a figure window, so just add an axes to it using the `axes` command, then the plot will appear in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wavread` takes a filename as first argument. As `audio` is not a file in your current path (or maybe not the one you want), you cannot put this as first argument.

But the variable `audio` holds the signal itself, so you don't need to access to the file itself anylonger. Then, initialize `fs` at the same time:

```
[audio,fs] = wavread(fullpathname);
```

Then, if you need to pick up a part of your signal, just get a slice of it:

```
x = audio(24120 25930);
```

For plotting, add axes in your GUI and call `plot` with the handle of these axes as first parameters (doc of Matlab is full of examples of that :) ).

Comment: @user3171222 Oups, I put `[]` instead of `()` for selecting slice. Edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[data,fs] = wavread(filename);

x = data(24120:25930);

% to plot data

plot(handles.axes1,t,x);

%%assuming you didn't change the name of handle to axis

Answer (score 0):

I tried your suggestions and I wrote it like this :

```
    % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
    function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    [filename pathname] = uigetfile({'*.wav'}, 'Select File');
    fullpathname = strcat (pathname, filename);
    [data,fs] = wavread(filename);



    % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
    function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    %MODEL
    % get a section of vowel
    x = data(24120:25930);
    ms20=fs/50; % minimum speech Fx at 50Hz
    %
    % plot waveform
    t=(0:length(x)-1)/fs; % times of sampling instants
    subplot(2,1,1);
    plot(t,x);
    legend('Waveform');
    xlabel('Time (s)');
    ylabel('Amplitude');
    plot(handles.axes1,t,x);
    %
    % calculate autocorrelation
    r=xcorr(x,ms20,'coeff');
    %
    % plot autocorrelation
    d=(-ms20:ms20)/fs; % times of delays
    subplot(2,1,2);
    plot(d,r);
    legend('Autocorrelation');
    xlabel('Delay (s)');
    ylabel('Correlation coeff.');
    plot(handles.axes2,d,r);
    ms2=fs/500 % maximum speech Fx at 500Hz
    ms20=fs/50 % minimum speech Fx at 50Hz
    % just look at region corresponding to positive delays
    r=r(ms20+1:2*ms20+1)
    [rmax,tx]=max(r(ms2:ms20))
    fprintf('rmax=%g Fx=%gHz\n',rmax,fs/(ms2+tx-1));
```

But I get the following erros:

```
?? Undefined function or method 'data' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in ==> untitled>pushbutton2_Callback at 94
x = data(24120:25930);

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> untitled at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==> @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Comment: The variable `data` is local to the function `function pushbutton1_Callback`, so it is not visible in the function `function pushbutton2_Callback`. Store it in the handle of the user data to pass it over the functions.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that? matlab confuses me :(

Comment: I think you can start by reading the Matlab doc for `guidata`, as it is gently proposed in the automatic comment generation of your code :)

Comment: Ok I think I got it..i defined the data and fs as global and used them..thank you :*

Answer (score 0):

ur problem was in the variable ure giving for wavread to read, instead of `[data,fs] = wavread(filename); use:[data,fs] = wavread(fullpathname)`. It worked for me.